# Disable microsoft's animations of updates to the HTML <progress> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

I have some code for a progress bar on a webpage, sample code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

    progress {
      background-color: #fff;
      height:40px;
      width:200px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    progress::-webkit-progress-bar {background-color: #fff;}
    progress::-webkit-progress-value {background-color: #cb8;}
    progress::-ms-fill {background-color: #cb8;}
    progress::-moz-progress-bar {background: #cb8;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <progress id="prog" value = 0 max = 50></progress>

  <script>
  const $ = s => document.getElementById(s)

  window.setInterval(function(){
    $("prog").value += 2;
    if($("prog").value >= $("prog").max){$("prog").value -= $("prog").max}
  }, 50);
  </script>
</body>
```

and finicky pseudo-elements aside it works well on chrome, opera, and firefox.

However, the Microsoft Edge browser insists on *animating* the transition each time the progress bar updates, which has the infuriating result of introducing a lot of lag and bizarre behavior when the value changes quickly.

I've tried everything I can think of to disable this behaviour on edge, but so far no luck with disabling this animation/transition. Any suggestions?

I'd really like to use the `<progress>` tag if possible, as being able to manipulate the `value` directly is much more convenient than updating the widths of nested divs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

    progress {
      background-color: #fff;
      height:40px;
      width:200px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    progress::-webkit-progress-bar {background-color: #fff;}
    progress::-webkit-progress-value {background-color: #cb8;}
    progress::-ms-fill {background-color: #cb8;}
    progress::-moz-progress-bar {background: #cb8;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <progress id="prog" value = 0 max = 50></progress>

  <script>
  const $ = function(s){ return document.getElementById(s) };

  window.setInterval(function(){
    $("prog").value += 2;
    if($("prog").value >= $("prog").max){$("prog").value -= $("prog").max}
  }, 50);
  </script>
</body>
```

Try this code . Its working both in chrome and Microsoft edge

Comment: That doesn't fix the behavior of Microsoft Edge trying to smooth out/animate/transition the updates to the progress bar. 

Compare chrome and edge here, when the bar rolls over on chrome, it's immediately updated on the screen to be 0% of the way full, while Edge trys to animate the transition, and as a result it lags, and never shows the bar being empty (or full, for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could not fix it. According to [this](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/animating-progress) blog post there's simply no way to change IE and Edge progress bar animations for now.